# Knockout and jQuery autocomplete

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, knockout.js, jquery-templates

Knockout value binding doesn't work with jquery autocomplte. How to get it working?

I have a template:

```
<input 
   type="text" 
   class="autocomplete" 
   data-bind="value: viewModelObservableValue"
   name="MyValue" />
```

After template rendering I am applying jQuery autocomplete on an input. Binding doesn't work. See my [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nonsense66/3vVDJ/).

It works only if `ko.applyBindings(viewModel)` goes after `$(..).autocomplete(..);`

Comment: alright got an answer for you. Interesting question

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It looks like jQuery autocomplete hijacked the `change` event. Thats why it doesn't work.

To fix this, you'll have to set the `valueUpdate` property to `blur`. Of course, this won't trigger after selecting the item, you'll have to blur first.

```js
$(function() {
    var availableTags = [
      "ActionScript",
      "AppleScript",
      "Asp",
      "BASIC",
      "C",
      "C++",
      "Clojure",
      "COBOL",
      "ColdFusion",
      "Scheme"
    ];
    $(".autocomplete").autocomplete({
      source: availableTags
    });
 });

var viewModel = {
    myValue: ko.observable()
};

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" class="autocomplete" data-bind="value: myValue, valueUpdate:'blur' " />

<div data-bind="text: myValue"></div>
```