# Not able to select / bind item from jquery autocomplete using Knockout JS

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, knockout.js, autocomplete

After I finally was able to add and remove items from a list ([see fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/spstieng/THJE3/46/)), I moved on to implement jQuery Autocomplete.

After looking at [Rune's example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15694425/connect-knockout-and-jqueryui-autocomplete) and [Rene's example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17676045/knockout-and-jquery-autocomplete), I am able to trigger Autocomplete. But when I select an item, the values are not added to my hidden input and my search box.

My current solution follows Rune's example, but I might simplyfy it and follow Rene's example once I'm able to bind the selected item.

So my question is: How can I bind the selected items? [I've created a Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/spstieng/JF55A/3/) to test.

*PS. I'm having issues in the Fiddle when putting search data in array (instead of getting from DB). But that is not my main problem.*

Here is the part of the code regarding Autocomplete:

My HTML:

```
<input type="hidden" value="" data-bind="value: item_id" />
<input class="form-control" type="search" data-bind="value: item_name, autoComplete: items" />     
...
<ul class="list-group" data-bind="template: { name: 'item-template', data: $root.items}">
...
</ul>
```

My JS;

```
// Retrieved from DB
var search_data = [
    {"id":"7186","name":"Bose"},
    {"id":"1069","name":"BOSS Black"},
    {"id":"1070","name":"BOSS Green"},
    {"id":"1071","name":"BOSS Hugo Boss"},
    {"id":"1072","name":"BOSS Orange"},
    {"id":"1074","name":"Boston Brothers"},
    {"id":"7678","name":"Bosweel"}
];

ko.bindingHandlers.autoComplete = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        var selectedObservableArrayInViewModel = valueAccessor();
        var self = bindingContext;
        self.item_id = ko.observable();
        self.item_name = ko.observable();    

        $(element).autocomplete({
            minLength: 2,
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    source: search_data,
                    data: { term: request.term },
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {
                        response(data);
                    }
                });
            },
            select: function(e, ui){
                var item = ui.item;
                self.item_name = ko.observable(item.name);
                self.item_id = ko.observable(item.id);
            }
        }).data( "uiAutocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
            return jQuery( "<li></li>" )
            .data( "ui-autocomplete", item )
            .append( "<a>"+ item.name + "</a>" )
            .appendTo( ul );
        }

    }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure I understand your question, so I am not sure this answers it.

First, you need to replace this

```
var self = bindingContext;
```

With this

```
var self = viewModel;
```

Then, in your select function, don't re-create your observables, update them and then call your `addItem` function:

```
select: function(e, ui){
            var item = ui.item;
            self.item_name(item.name);
            self.item_id(item.id);
            self.addItem();
        }
```

**Updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/P8N77/)** (I removed your ajax call to show all items without filtering, just for the demo -- ajax call was failing)

**EDIT:**

In the previous fiddle, the input is cleared after the selection of an item.

Add `return false;` to the end of the `select` function to avoid that.

**New [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/P8N77/1/)**

Comment: That works great, thanks! Just one thing. If I remove `self.addItem()`, why isn't my selection showing in the search box?

Comment: @Steven What do you call the search box? Is it the list of found items? The found items are filled with the call to the `response` function. The `select` function is called when you click on one of the found items, this is the place where you need to add the item to the `items` observableArray.

Comment: Exactly. So when I click it, I want to see the name in the search box. The searchbox is the `<input class="form-control"...` input. Currently, name is not shown, but clicking `Add` will add my selection to the list. Do I have to use `$('.form-control').val(item.name)` as well?

Comment: @Steven answer updated. It's often a `return false` to avoid further action