# Why isn't my jQuery autocomplete data-binding using Knockout JS?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, knockout.js, autocomplete

So I've [successfully been able to implement autocomplete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23711542/not-able-to-select-bind-item-from-jquery-autocomplete-using-knockout-js) which adds item to a list ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sherin81/JF55A/11/)).

Now I need to use jQuery UI autocomplete to populate some data fields. Still trying to wrap my head around Knockout, I don't think I've successfully bound the autocomplete.

I thought `data-bind="autocompleteAddress: items` would trigger my `data-bind="autocompleteAddress`, but nothing is happening ([see me fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/spstieng/n26MA/))

Is there something obvious I'm missing?

My code looks like this:

```
// HTML (the 'source:' is used for my ajax call. Not used in the fiddle)
    <input  
        type="text" 
        data-bind="autocompleteAddress: {source: '/address/autocompleteAddress'}" 
        name="Address[street1]" 
        value="Stovner Senter 3" 
        placeholder="Enter street name" 
        class="street1 form-control ui-autocomplete-input" 
        autocomplete="off" />


// JS    
var search_data = [
 {"id": "7186","street1": "Bose","street2": "","postal_code": "0521","city": "Oslo","country":"Norway"}, 
 {"id": "1069","street1": "BOSS Black","street2": "","postal_code": "0531","city": "Oslo","country":"Norway"}, 
 {"id": "1070","street1": "BOSS Green","street2": "","postal_code": "0522","city": "Oslo","country":"Norway"}
];

ko.bindingHandlers.autocompleteAddress = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {        
        var postUrl = site_url + allBindingsAccessor().source; //Not used here
        var self = viewModel;        

        $(element).autocomplete({
            minLength: 2,
            source: function (request, response) {
                response(search_data);
            },
            select: function (e, ui) {
                var item = ui.item;

            }
        }).data("uiAutocomplete")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
            return jQuery("<li></li>")
                .data("ui-autocomplete", item)
                .append("<a>" + item.street1 + ' ' + item.city + "</a>")
                .appendTo(ul);
        }

    }
};
```

Comment: I had worked on this from your older/deleted question. See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/origineil/P8N77/15/). I updated the data to that provided in this post.

Comment: That's fantastic @Origineil! Can you post a short answer here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So based on the original question (which was deleted), the problem was that you wanted to bind a set of `address` properties when a user selected an item from `autocomplete`.

The same problem as mentioned by GSerjo was present in that fiddle as well -- no `ko.applyBindings` was used. It was there just commented out, so that fixed the `autocomplete` showing up.

The next issue was that the values weren't showing up in the fields. Adding `return false` at the  end of the `select` function of the autocomplete seemed to address that issue. *I don't know what significance that has, I'll have to look into that.*

Other than that, I cleaned up some of the html and provided an `Address` constructor.

```
var Address = function (data) {
 this.address_id = ko.observable(data.id);
 this.street1 = ko.observable(data.street1);
 this.street2 = ko.observable(data.street2);  
 this.postal_code = ko.observable(data.postal_code);
 this.city = ko.observable(data.city);
 this.country = ko.observable(data.country);  
};
```

The viewmodel:

```
var vm = {
  items: ko.observableArray(search_data),
  address: ko.observable({})
}
```

The autocomplete binding:

```
<input type="text" class='street1 form-control' data-bind="autocompleteAddress: items, valueUpdate:'afterKeyDown', value: address().street1, attr:{placeholder: 'Enter street name'}"></input>
```

When a user makes a selection,

```
 select: function (e, ui) {
          viewModel.address(new Address(ui.item))
          return false;
         }
```

See [the updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/origineil/P8N77/15/)

Comment: There is one problem with this solution. You are resetting the input fields. I need keep the content. How do you go about that? I feel this is a "global" issue with Knockout. You have to write extra code in order to keep server side loaded data. Is there a way to keep server side data?

Comment: Not exactly clear on what you mean by "keep" and "resetting". If you set the initial `viewmodel` to be that of the server-side data, then that is the data that will be displayed. So instead of `address: ko.observable({})` you would replace the empty object `{}` with some `address` item from the server. Either `search_data` or `items` would always be the representation of `loaded data` from the server.

Comment: So I have to pass the server data to the viewModel then in turn put it back in the HTML? That seems a bit backward. Can't I just output the data in the html `<?= $some->data; ?>` and tell Knockout to leave it alone? :) I know Angular JS leaves the data as is when it comes from the server.

Comment: The viewModel gets put into the HTML via `ko.applyBindings` you just have to tell it how you want it displayed. The HTML is `bound` to the model, so if you have "loaded" something outside of the `apply`, knockout doesn't know about it. So if I'm not mistaken, you are asking why you can't say something like `value='Oslo'` in the html and have knockout not change that?

Comment: Yeah. But not just `value='Oslo'`. Also `<div data-bind="text: foo">Some data from server here</div>`. Once I add `data-bind`, the content of the div / input gets empty. When the page renders, it also renders the content retrieved from server (right), so Knockout should know it has content and therefore should return that content.

Comment: Discussion moved to separate [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23984658/how-do-i-keep-data-loaded-from-the-server-from-getting-blanked-out-by-knockout)

Answer (score 1):

Knockout doesn't apply your binding because `ko.applyBindings` is absent. So, just add `ko.applyBindings({});` at the bottom of the code.

Here's updated [version](http://jsfiddle.net/GSerjo/n26MA/6/)

Note: you can debug the code with `F12` and `debugger;` key word. For instance:

- Write `debugger;` in the `init` function
- Press `F12` in your favorite browser and you see that the binding was not called

Comment: Yeah, I was wondering about that because I'm already using `ko.applyBindings`for two other view models. So I thought that would be enough. Can I somehow do this `var addViewModel = ko.bindingHandlers.autocompleteAddress...` ? I'm using Firebug all the time, but didn't know about the `debuger;`. Thanks.

Comment: yes, you can, it's JavaScript :) but what is your aim? You can move `ko.bindingHandlers.autocompleteAddress` script on top loading level. i.e. first of all your binding will be initialized and then applied