# How do I keep data loaded from the server from getting "blanked out" by Knockout JS on page load?

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I'm trying to understand Knockout JS. What bothers me is that the data I bind gets *blanked out*. It's annoying because I want to show the data I retrieve from the server.

An example:

```
Name: <span class="name"><?php echo $data->name; ?></span>
```

The result is: `Name: John B`

Now if I data-bind this with Knockout to this:

```
Name: <span data-bind="text: name" class="name"><?php echo $data->name; ?></span>
```

The result is: `Name:`

The JS will be something like:

```
var viewModel = {
    name: ko.observable() // Initially blank <--- this is the culprit
};
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

So what do I need to do in order to show / keep the data?
Can't Knockout somehow keep the data like Angular JS does?

**Note**
I'm using Yii MVC framework to handle a lot of server side stuff. Using that to load data on page load, saves me from writing a lot of JS Ajax code. I wanted to use Knockout to reduce the amount of jQuery code I have, not add to it :)

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative is to construct your viewmodel supplying your value from the server directly into the observable.

```
<span data-bind="text: name"></span>
```

---

```
var viewModel = {
  name: ko.observable(<?php echo $data->name; ?>);
};

ko.applyBindings();
```

Trying to initialise an observable's value from the HTML is dangerous as there are many ways that the observable's value will be reset, specifically if an element is contained within a parent binding that uses a explicit/implicit template, like an `if` binding.

```
<div data-bind="if: someFlag">
    <span data-bind="text: name">John Doe</span>
<div>
```

In the above example, everytime the `someFlag` value changes from false to true, the text binding on the span element will be re-initialised.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Robert, but putting a lot of JS code in the HTML is not an option.

Comment: wtf "but putting a lot of JS code in the HTML is not an option." Steven? The only thing he did was to move your php from html to your viewmodel initialization. What are you talking about?

Comment: @Buzinas the ViewModel is probably in a separate js file (should be), if you want to include php code you need to move from the js file to the php/html file

Answer (score 2):

Here are two workaround you can try to avoid declaring your data twice (note that they do not directly provide a way to keep your data in your html file) :

### Solution 1: Put your default model in a separate js/php file

Create a php file with:

```
var defaultVm = {
    name: '<?php echo $data->name; ?>',
    anyVariable: '<?php echo $data->anyVariable; ?>'
}
```

Then you include this php file as a js file and init your viewmodel with it:

```
var viewModel = {
    name: ko.observable(defaultVm.name);
    anyVariable: ko.observable(defaultVm.anyVariable);
};
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

### Solution 2: Use the [ko.mapping](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html) plugin

Create a php file with:

```
{
    "name": "<?php echo $data->name; ?>",
    "anyVariable": "<?php echo $data->anyVariable; ?>"
}
```

Then in your js, you can use the ko.mapping plugin:

```
var viewModel = function (data) {
    ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, this);
};
ko.applyBindings(new viewModel(getYourPhpFileTheWayYoulike));
```

This allows you to get your data asynchronously (if you want) with something like:

```
$.getJSON("yourphpmodelurl", function (data) {
    ViewModelInstance = new viewModel(data);
    ko.applyBindings(ViewModelInstance);
}
```

Comment: Thanks GoTo. But what about Kennet's solution? With my modificaations, this seems like a good solution. Any drawbacks here?  http://jsfiddle.net/P8N77/26/

Comment: @Steven Personnally I like the possibility to view the viewmodel I start with by accessing the url. But as I can see in your fiddle, what you wanted was to **not** set the value of your viewmodel but keep it displayed? (address is empty at load time http://jsfiddle.net/nyothecat/P8N77/27/)

Comment: Not sure what you mean, but address is not empty at load time. It's fetch from the server and displayed on page load (se my example in my question)

Comment: @Steven You removed the part where the observable is updated at load time (see the `init` function in Kenneth's solution). If you check the fiddle in which I just displayed the view model, you'll notice at the end that `address` is `{}` and takes a value only when you set one of the fields

Comment: I removed it because it works without it. It seems that all that it needs is the ´update:´ section. As you can see, when the page load, the input fields keeps their values. Or am I misunderstanding something here?

Comment: @Steven the values are kept in the HTML, but the viewmodel is not updated. That means if your were to post it to the server like this, you would not get anything for the address. Also, if you had computed observables based on the address, their value would be wrong. Take this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nyothecat/P8N77/28/) for example, and see how Street1 gets updated (or not) in the span

Comment: @Steven binding should be both ways: update the viewmodel when the UI is changed, update the UI whend the viewmodel is changed. ViewModel should be a representation of the UI at all times

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54931/discussion-between-steven-and-goto).

Comment: Kenneth's solution fails if any binding is within a template, like "if" or "foreach".  The init function is called whenever KO need to initialise that DOM element, not just once per page render.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom binding handler to do this:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.textInitialized= {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        valueAccessor()(element.innerHTML); // get the current value and update the observable
    },
    update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        var value = valueAccessor();
        element.innerHTML = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(value);
    }
};
```

And then you can bind to your viewmodel like this:

```
Name: <span data-bind="textInitialized: name" class="name">John B</span>
```

EDIT after jsFiddle:

You have created a completely different thing in the jsFiddle. 
A few things:

1. Inside your autocomplethandler, you use the code I provided, but: you want to set the "value"-attribute, not the innerHTML, so you should change that to `element.value` instead of `element.innerHTML`.
2. You have both an autocomplete-binding and a value-binding. Both of them work on the value-attribute (if you follow my first comment). The second one will come in after the first and undo that change.

I have modified the fiddle with these changes: http://jsfiddle.net/P8N77/24/

Comment: Thanks @Kenneth. So I tried applying this solution to a specific example: http://jsfiddle.net/P8N77/23/, but the fields are still blank on page load. Any suggestions to what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I edited my answer and posted a correction of the fiddle

Comment: In addtion, change the view model `address: ko.observable({})` to `address: ko.observable(new Address({}))` so the valueAccessor has an observable to initialize

Comment: You will encounted problems if your binding in contained within an explicit/implicit template, like "if", "foreach" or "template".  The init method will be invoked again resetting the observable's value.

Comment: You also need to add a value binding any input with the initialData binding ( otherwise knockout will not update your observable is the inout's value changes ), or call `ko.bindingHandlers['value'].init` and `ko.bindinhHandlers['value'].update` from your respective init and update methods

Comment: If you add `data-bind="if: address().showStreet2"` to the li parent of the street2 input, then add `this.showStreet2 = ko.observable(true);` to the address class, finally add a checkbox to the HTML bound to that new observable.  Toggling that checkbox will reset the value of the observable back to the initial state.

Comment: The problem with this method is that you will need to enhance the bindinghandler (or create a new one) for every existing binding handler (here you did it with `text`, you would probably need `value` too for example)

Comment: @Kenneth I see the logic in that. But your updated fiddle throws an error: `TypeError: valueAccessor(...) is not a function`.

Comment: Hey, I got it to work using this: http://jsfiddle.net/P8N77/26/ Simple and clean?